# Primitive to user defined assignment on construction

Tags: c++, constructor, assignment-operator

Sorry for the blurry title, I seem to be missing something.

I was hesitant to post this, because it seems so basic, but I can't get it to work. My IDE tells me the following is incorrect. I have a class called IRatio which I want to be interchangeable with long double.

```
class
IRatio
{
    protected:
        long double 
        mValue;

    public:
        IRatio();

        IRatio(
            const IRatio& ir);

        IRatio(
            const long double& ld);

        IRatio&
        operator=(
            const IRatio& ir);

        IRatio&
        operator=(
            const long double& ld);

        operator long double() const;
};
```

Now I know that the following lines work:

```
IRatio n1(0.01f);
IRatio n2;
n2 = 0.02f;
```

However, to my complete suprise, this line doesn't work:

```
IRatio n3 = 0.03f;
```

How do I get this to work? I assumed the copy constructor was called in this case? Or even if it was the assignment operator, I don't mind! I know that std::string can do it.

```
std::string s = "hello!";
```

Thanks

Comment: How exactly it _it doesn't work_ ? Compiler error or wrong result?

Comment: long double is not part of the current C++ standard. which compiler are you using?

Comment: @unapersson, you and the one who upvoted your comment are wrong :).

Comment: @litb Oops, you are as usual right - I was thinking of long long. I'd still  like to know which compiler he's using, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *should* work as is. That said, `IRatio` doesn't manage any resources on its own, so you don't need the copy constructor and assignment operator. This should do:

```
struct IRatio {
    IRatio() : d(0L) { }
    IRatio(long double d) : d(d) { }
    operator long double() const { return d; }
private:
    long double d;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IRatio r = 0.02f;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. However, `0.03f` is of type `float`. You want to say `0.03L` to say `long double`. But this doesn't necessarily matter here, `float` is convertible to `long double`.

Yes, the constructor with parameter `const long double&` would be used to create a temporary `IRatio` object, which would be copied to `n3` (and your compiler should optimizes the copy, so you are likely not to see a copy constructor call here, unless you have told it not to optimize).